# Error when parsing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in PHP while Apache Server mod_rewrite is on

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, request, uri

I'm trying to use Apache's mod_rewrite to create better URLs. I'm redirecting everything to a single index.php page, parsing the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and then including the appropriate pages.

The code for the RewriteRule is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \b.*\b index.php
```

I made a url class to handle url manipulation, and inside it there is this function to get the URL:

```
public function get_url(){
    $url = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $url = explode("/", $url);
    array_shift($url);
    print_r($url);
    return $url;
}
```

It works, but there's a problem: the explode function causes the last array index to be null when there is a / character, which bothers me and make things more complicated when including the right page. That should be easy to fix, doing some cheap manipulation such as:

```
$url = trim(str_replace(" ", "/", $url));
$url = explode(" ", $url);
```

But whenever I try to change the $url variable (which is a copy of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) in any way other than what I wrote above, I get this error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>       cookies.

My guess is that somehow the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is being passed by reference, and when I try to manipulate the string the Apache server can't find a match and goes bananas, but I have no idea why this could be happening (or why exploding with a / delimiter is ok but changing the / character to whitespace and then exploding is not) or, more importantly, how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not connected to your PHP at all.

You simply told the apache to rewrite that Request again and again, which results in the Firefox statement you posted.

To avoid a rewrite when index.php is addressed already, you have to add a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!(index\.php.*)
RewriteRule \b.*\b index.php
```

This way the rule only applies if URI does not start with "index.php" and therefore not has been rewritten yet

Regards,

STEFAN